# How windows 8 relates app tiles and secondary tiles with the application?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How does windows 8 know which application to launch when you click to app tile or secondary tile?

Comment: When I looked at the title I read _relates_ as _hates_. o_0

Answer (score 3):

What is your question really asking about?

If you are asking how does the OS knows which tile is associated with the Secondary Tile with the parent app, my guess would be there is a `appID` kind of thing related to each tile. Each secondary tile works as a "short cut" on the Start Menu, so that you can launch the app with some special parameter. The special parameter that you want pass to the application when you launch the app are specified in the method as the 4th argument (called `argument`) when you create your tile.

```
var secondaryTile = new Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile(tileId, shortName, displayName, arguments, tileOptions, logoReference);
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701602.aspx

But behind the scene, I don't know how Microsoft implements it in their API.

If you are asking how to implement `Secondary Tile` in Metro Style App. This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465372.aspx) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, Louis. "If you are asking how does the OS knows which tile is associated with the Secondary Tile with the parent app, my guess would be there is a appID kind of thing related to each tile." - I agree with you, but when I set empty string to 'arguments' parameter and nothing happened after click to secondary tile, I began to doubt this.